# Which directory can be used to store data and will be wiped when uninstall on macOS (Installed from Mac App Store)?

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

I am writing an Electron app. **I want to store user settings and want the settings to be wiped on uninstall, but persists on update.**

So the regular `app.getPath("userData")` doesn't fit since it persists after uninstall. My attempt is to use `path.resolve(process.resourcesPath,"../../");` which results in `%LocalAppData%/my_app` in windows and `/Applications/MyApp.app` in Mac. This works on windows and darwin, but on mas (Mac App Store) build this directory is not writable.

Is it possible/How to make this path writable on mas build? or

Is there a more appropriate path to store the data which will get wipe on uninstall but not on update? or

Is there a more appropriate way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

As the app is sandboxed and managed by App Store, its container will be deleted when uninstall. So `app.getPath("userData")` can be used in a mas build and still achieving "wipe data on uninstall, persists on update". So the solution is to use

```
process.mas ? app.getPath("userData") : path.resolve(process.resourcesPath,"../../");
```